# Blank check causing extra count call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am hardly trying to find one comparison of result.blank? and result[0] so finally today when i was checking one query with these two methods.

Here the code, result variable is @categories, which is an ActiveRecord result

This blank check calling one extra db call like SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all

```
if @categories.blank?
end
```

But here that extra query is not showing there.

```
if @categories[0]
end
```

Is there any logic behind that? I couldn't find that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to note that assigning a ActiveRecord query to a variable does not return the result of the query. Something like this:

```
@categories = Category.where(public: true)
```

Does not return an array with all categories that are public. Instead it returns an [`Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) which defines an query. The query to the database is execute once you call a method in the relation that needs to return the actual record, for example `each`, `load`, `count`.

That said: When you call `blank?` on a relation Rails needs to know it the relation will not return an empty array. Therefore Rails executes an query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories WHERE public = 1
```

Because that queries is much faster that fetching all records when the only thing you need to know if there are any matching records.

Whereas `@categories[0]` works differently. Here it need to load all records to have an array holding all macthing categories and than return the first record in that array.

At this point both version ran only on query to the database. But I guess your next step would be to iterate over the records if there were any. If you used the first version (`blank?`) then the objects were not loaded, they were only counted. Therefore Rails would need to query for the actual records, what would result in a second query. The second exmaple (`[0]`) has the records already loaded, therefore not seconds query in needed.

Comment: so as your thought what would be the best way, because for that count query i got timeout, thats why i did check

Comment: If you plan iterate over the result set after checking if there are any records, then I would consider using `unless @categories.length.zero?`. Because `length` always loads the records first, whereas `count` never does and `size` would fall back to `count` if the records have not been loaded before. Regarding timeouts, how does the query look like, do you have appropriate indexes in the database table in place?

Comment: This my analyze https://explain.depesz.com/s/cHQy , live this took around 11980ms